# Skew Image in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

[image: need to skew image without loosing height of image/imageview using slider]

Need to skew image without loosing height of image/imageview using slider
I have tried 3d transform but it is not keeping height same.

--edits
Using below code

float angle = (360 * self.slider.value);

```
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, angle * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

self.marker.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

This works and rotate in 3d but I need to skew image as given in image

Comment: You need to show us the code that you're using that's not working right; That will give folks a better chance to help you out.

Comment: float angle = (360 * self.slider.value);
   
    
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, angle * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        
    self.marker.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

Comment: Using this code, it works but it do 3d transform so it will decrease height of image view. I just want to skew image so it just work same as I saw in image

Answer (score 0):

I got solution on my own from other answers

```
- (IBAction)onSkewChange:(UISlider *)sender {

    if (sender.tag == 100) {
        self.bottomSlider.value=0;
    }else if (sender.tag == 200) {
        self.topSlider.value=0;
    }

    [self skewTestOnLayer:self.photoImageView.layer];
}

-(void)skewTestOnLayer:(CALayer*)l{

    float topValue = (self.photoImageView.frame.size.width * (self.topSlider.value/100) )/2;
    float bottomValue = (self.photoImageView.frame.size.width * (self.bottomSlider.value/100) )/2;

    CGPoint topLeft = CGPointMake(l.frame.origin.x + topValue, l.frame.origin.y);
    CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(l.frame.origin.x + l.frame.size.width - topValue, l.frame.origin.y);


    CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(l.frame.origin.x + bottomValue, l.frame.origin.y+l.frame.size.height);
    CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(l.frame.origin.x+l.frame.size.width - bottomValue, l.frame.origin.y+l.frame.size.height);

    [self transformToFitQuadTopLeft:topLeft topRight:topRight bottomLeft:bottomLeft bottomRight:bottomRight];

}

- (void)transformToFitQuadTopLeft:(CGPoint)tl topRight:(CGPoint)tr bottomLeft:(CGPoint)bl bottomRight:(CGPoint)br
{
    self.photoImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    CGRect boundingBox = [[self class] boundingBoxForQuadTR:tr tl:tl bl:bl br:br];
    //NSLog(@"bounding box = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(boundingBox));
    self.photoImageView.frame = boundingBox;

    CGPoint frameTopLeft = boundingBox.origin;
    CATransform3D transform = [[self class] rectToQuad:self.photoImageView.bounds
                                                quadTL:CGPointMake(tl.x-frameTopLeft.x, tl.y-frameTopLeft.y)
                                                quadTR:CGPointMake(tr.x-frameTopLeft.x, tr.y-frameTopLeft.y)
                                                quadBL:CGPointMake(bl.x-frameTopLeft.x, bl.y-frameTopLeft.y)
                                                quadBR:CGPointMake(br.x-frameTopLeft.x, br.y-frameTopLeft.y)];

    self.photoImageView.layer.transform = transform;

}

+ (CGRect)boundingBoxForQuadTR:(CGPoint)tr tl:(CGPoint)tl bl:(CGPoint)bl br:(CGPoint)br
{
    CGRect boundingBox = CGRectZero;

    CGFloat xmin = MIN(MIN(MIN(tr.x, tl.x), bl.x),br.x);
    CGFloat ymin = MIN(MIN(MIN(tr.y, tl.y), bl.y),br.y);
    CGFloat xmax = MAX(MAX(MAX(tr.x, tl.x), bl.x),br.x);
    CGFloat ymax = MAX(MAX(MAX(tr.y, tl.y), bl.y),br.y);

    boundingBox.origin.x = xmin;
    boundingBox.origin.y = ymin;
    boundingBox.size.width = xmax - xmin;
    boundingBox.size.height = ymax - ymin;

    return boundingBox;
}

+ (CATransform3D)rectToQuad:(CGRect)rect
                     quadTL:(CGPoint)topLeft
                     quadTR:(CGPoint)topRight
                     quadBL:(CGPoint)bottomLeft
                     quadBR:(CGPoint)bottomRight
{
    return [self rectToQuad:rect quadTLX:topLeft.x quadTLY:topLeft.y quadTRX:topRight.x quadTRY:topRight.y quadBLX:bottomLeft.x quadBLY:bottomLeft.y quadBRX:bottomRight.x quadBRY:bottomRight.y];
}

+ (CATransform3D)rectToQuad:(CGRect)rect
                    quadTLX:(CGFloat)x1a
                    quadTLY:(CGFloat)y1a
                    quadTRX:(CGFloat)x2a
                    quadTRY:(CGFloat)y2a
                    quadBLX:(CGFloat)x3a
                    quadBLY:(CGFloat)y3a
                    quadBRX:(CGFloat)x4a
                    quadBRY:(CGFloat)y4a
{
    CGFloat X = rect.origin.x;
    CGFloat Y = rect.origin.y;
    CGFloat W = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat H = rect.size.height;

    CGFloat y21 = y2a - y1a;
    CGFloat y32 = y3a - y2a;
    CGFloat y43 = y4a - y3a;
    CGFloat y14 = y1a - y4a;
    CGFloat y31 = y3a - y1a;
    CGFloat y42 = y4a - y2a;

    CGFloat a = -H*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42);
    CGFloat b = W*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43);
    CGFloat c = H*X*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x2a*x4a*y31 - x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x3a*y42) - H*W*x1a*(x4a*y32 - x3a*y42 + x2a*y43) - W*Y*(x2a*x3a*y14 + x3a*x4a*y21 + x1a*x4a*y32 + x1a*x2a*y43);

    CGFloat d = H*(-x4a*y21*y3a + x2a*y1a*y43 - x1a*y2a*y43 - x3a*y1a*y4a + x3a*y2a*y4a);
    CGFloat e = W*(x4a*y2a*y31 - x3a*y1a*y42 - x2a*y31*y4a + x1a*y3a*y42);
    CGFloat f = -(W*(x4a*(Y*y2a*y31 + H*y1a*y32) - x3a*(H + Y)*y1a*y42 + H*x2a*y1a*y43 + x2a*Y*(y1a - y3a)*y4a + x1a*Y*y3a*(-y2a + y4a)) - H*X*(x4a*y21*y3a - x2a*y1a*y43 + x3a*(y1a - y2a)*y4a + x1a*y2a*(-y3a + y4a)));

    CGFloat g = H*(x3a*y21 - x4a*y21 + (-x1a + x2a)*y43);
    CGFloat h = W*(-x2a*y31 + x4a*y31 + (x1a - x3a)*y42);
    CGFloat i = W*Y*(x2a*y31 - x4a*y31 - x1a*y42 + x3a*y42) + H*(X*(-(x3a*y21) + x4a*y21 + x1a*y43 - x2a*y43) + W*(-(x3a*y2a) + x4a*y2a + x2a*y3a - x4a*y3a - x2a*y4a + x3a*y4a));

    const double kEpsilon = 0.0001;

    if(fabs(i) < kEpsilon)
    {
        i = kEpsilon* (i > 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0);
    }

    CATransform3D transform = {a/i, d/i, 0, g/i, b/i, e/i, 0, h/i, 0, 0, 1, 0, c/i, f/i, 0, 1.0};

    return transform;
}
```